# How to switch between bluetooth and wifi in esp32

Tags: http, bluetooth, wifi, arduino-ide, esp32

I am doing an autonomous car project, I need manual control as well as an autonomous function, so the manual control is done through wif using "gesture control" and for the autonomous control I want to send the location data via Bluetooth, I will be choosing between both, using a toggle switch connected to ground and one of the pins. I went through the inbuilt wifi Bluetooth switch program but I have no idea how to modify it. I am still okay if I can send data through the HTTP request but, then I have to connect it to a network right? But again I don't have any idea, how to write the code to switch between the two networks.**I am using an ESP32 devkit**

This is the inbuilt example code for Bluetooth switch

```
#include "WiFi.h"
#define STA_SSID "your-ssid"
#define STA_PASS "your-pass"
#define AP_SSID  "esp32"

enum { STEP_BTON, STEP_BTOFF, STEP_STA, STEP_AP, STEP_AP_STA, STEP_OFF, STEP_BT_STA, STEP_END };

void onButton(){
  static uint32_t step = STEP_BTON;
  switch(step){
    case STEP_BTON://BT Only
      Serial.println("** Starting BT");
      btStart();
    break;
    case STEP_BTOFF://All Off
      Serial.println("** Stopping BT");
      btStop();
    break;
    case STEP_STA://STA Only
      Serial.println("** Starting STA");
      WiFi.begin(STA_SSID, STA_PASS);
    break;
    case STEP_AP://AP Only
      Serial.println("** Stopping STA");
      WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
      Serial.println("** Starting AP");
      WiFi.softAP(AP_SSID);
    break;
    case STEP_AP_STA://AP+STA
      Serial.println("** Starting STA");
      WiFi.begin(STA_SSID, STA_PASS);
    break;
    case STEP_OFF://All Off
      Serial.println("** Stopping WiFi");
      WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);
    break;
    case STEP_BT_STA://BT+STA
      Serial.println("** Starting STA+BT");
      WiFi.begin(STA_SSID, STA_PASS);
      btStart();
    break;
    case STEP_END://All Off
      Serial.println("** Stopping WiFi+BT");
      WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);
      btStop();
    break;
    default:
    break;
  }
  if(step == STEP_END){
    step = STEP_BTON;
  } else {
    step++;
  }
  //little debounce
  delay(100);
}

void WiFiEvent(WiFiEvent_t event){
    switch(event) {
        case SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_START:
            Serial.println("AP Started");
            WiFi.softAPsetHostname(AP_SSID);
            break;
        case SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STOP:
            Serial.println("AP Stopped");
            break;
        case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_START:
            Serial.println("STA Started");
            WiFi.setHostname(AP_SSID);
            break;
        case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_CONNECTED:
            Serial.println("STA Connected");
            WiFi.enableIpV6();
            break;
        case SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STA_GOT_IP6:
            Serial.print("STA IPv6: ");
            Serial.println(WiFi.localIPv6());
            break;
        case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP:
            Serial.print("STA IPv4: ");
            Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
            break;
        case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED:
            Serial.println("STA Disconnected");
            break;
        case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_STOP:
            Serial.println("STA Stopped");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    pinMode(0, INPUT_PULLUP);
    WiFi.onEvent(WiFiEvent);
    Serial.print("ESP32 SDK: ");
    Serial.println(ESP.getSdkVersion());
    Serial.println("Press the button to select the next mode");
}

void loop() {
    static uint8_t lastPinState = 1;
    uint8_t pinState = digitalRead(0);
    if(!pinState && lastPinState){
        onButton();
    }
    lastPinState = pinState;
}
```

Below is part of the main code i use, i want to modify it so i can either switch between bluetooth and esp now or between espnow and http

```
*/
#include <esp_now.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <esp_wifi.h>
#include <TinyGPS++.h>          // Tiny GPS Plus Library 


#define CHANNEL 4

uint8_t mac[] = {0x36, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33};

struct __attribute__((packed)) DataStruct {
    //char text[32];
    int x;
    int y;
    unsigned long time;
};

DataStruct myData;

  //*****************************************************************************************************
// GPS Locations

unsigned long Distance_To_Home;                                    // variable for storing the distance to destination

int ac =0;                                                         // GPS array counter
int wpCount = 0;                                                   // GPS waypoint counter
double Home_LATarray[50];                                          // variable for storing the destination Latitude - Only Programmed for 5 waypoint
double Home_LONarray[50];                                          // variable for storing the destination Longitude - up to 50 waypoints

int increment = 0;

#define autopilot 13
 void  gesturecontroll();
 void getGPS();    
 void getCompass();  

void setWaypoint();

 void move();

 int blueToothVal;  


void setup() 
{    Serial.begin(9600);                                            // Serial 0 is for communication with the computer
     S2.begin(9600);                                             // Serial 2 is for GPS communication at 9600 baud - DO NOT MODIFY - Ublox Neo 6m 


 Serial.println("ESPNow/Basic/Slave Example");
  //Set device in AP mode to begin with
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  // configure device AP mode
  // This is the mac address of the Slave in AP Mode
  esp_wifi_set_mac(ESP_IF_WIFI_STA, &mac[0]);


  Serial.print("AP MAC: "); Serial.println(WiFi.softAPmacAddress());
  // Init ESPNow with a fallback logic
  if (esp_now_init()!=0) {
        Serial.println("*** ESP_Now init failed");
        while(true) {};
    }

  // Once ESPNow is successfully Init, we will register for recv CB to
  // get recv packer info.
  esp_now_register_recv_cb(OnDataRecv);
   Serial.print("Aheloiioi");


 // Extras////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     pinMode(autopilot, INPUT);



}
void OnDataRecv(const uint8_t *mac_addr, const uint8_t *data, int data_len) {
  memcpy(&myData, data, sizeof(myData));
  char macStr[18];
  snprintf(macStr, sizeof(macStr), "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
           mac_addr[0], mac_addr[1], mac_addr[2], mac_addr[3], mac_addr[4], mac_addr[5]);
  Serial.print("Last Packet Recv from: "); Serial.println(macStr);
  Serial.print("Last Packet Recv Data: "); 
  Serial.println(myData.x); 
  Serial.println(myData.y);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println();
  //move();
  Serial.println();
} 

//********************************************************************************************************
// Main Loop

void loop()
{ if (autopilot == HIGH)
    {
       move();                                                  // going for manual control

      } 
  else
  { 
    getGPS();                                                        // Update the GPS location
    getCompass();                                                    // Update the CompaSerial Heading
    Ping();                                                          // Use at your own discretion, this is not fully tested

    }    

}
```

I could have tried if all these initial setups came under an "if statement" in the void loop, but these initial setups come in the void setup,so i have no idea on how to proced

Answer (score 0):

1. I think this example need hardware also like toggle switch between GPIO 0 & ground on top of the code these comments are there.

//Sketch shows how to switch between Wi-Fi and Bluetooth or use both
// Button is attached between GPIO 0 and GND and modes are switched with each press

2. this example code as wifi.h library included but "BluetoothSerial.h" library is not included I don't it works properly in real time without this "BluetoothSerial.h" library
3. About terminology in ESP32 Wi-Fi go through it:- https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/network/esp_wifi.html

I think first prepare hardware as given in example then start coding.